# How to insert a section header on its own page centered vertically and horizontally?

Tags: rmarkdown

I'm using R Markdown and knitting to pdf. I'd like to have a `# Header` centered vertically and horizontally on its own page. Unfortuinately,

```
\center # Header \center
```

and

```
\begin{centering}
# Header
\end{centering}
```

don't work for me.

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: It's an R Markdown file.